# New ISP now my local WAMP not connecting to external APIs (501)

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp

I have a local WAMP 3.2.0 setup to do my php coding on my local PC. It was setup and worked fine. I have recently changed Internet service providers and now my php code that access external API sites does not work. The call seems to come back with a

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501 (Not Implemented)
```

response.  The code when loaded on an external server does work. Any idea where I even begin to debug this?

Comment: CheI'd start by checking whether you can reach the API domains / URLs in your web browser, and that the DNS resolves to the correct IP address(es).

Comment: could be an issue with IPv6, if your new ISP requesting over IPv6 and the API server is not set up for IPv6

Comment: @CBroe All websites open as usual.

Comment: @MikeMoy The IPv6 is disabled by the router I enabled it but I still had the same issue